# Is it possible to add Extra Fields Under Create User in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 for portal Development .
During Creating Users under Liferay , i need to add some extra Fields also ??
Please let me know if this is ppossible or not ??

Please see the screen shot attached here , and also please let me know in which table this will be stored in Database ??

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can use [Custom Attributes functionality](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+use+Custom+Attributes+to+enhance+Users)  for liferay entities (in your case, User) and can add as many extra fields as necessary for each liferay entity.

Custom field for the user-entity can be created through:
<kbd>Control Panel</kbd> `->` <kbd>Portal</kbd> `->` <kbd>Custom Fields</kbd> `->` <kbd>User</kbd>.

And programmatically can be created as follows:

```
user.getExpandoBridge().addAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey");
```

Then set the value as:

```
user.getExpandoBridge().setAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey", "valueForCustomField");
```

If your custom field is already present you can check like this:

```
if (user.getExpandoBridge().hasAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey")) { ... };
```

The data is stored in tables prefixed with **"EXPANDO"**:

- **EXPANDOCOLUMN:** stores the custom field key and other settings
  (contains the tableId refrences)
- **EXPANDODATA:** stores the custom field value for the key (contains the
  columnId and tableId refrences)
- **EXPANDOTABLE:** stores for which liferay entity (user) are you adding
  the custom field
- **EXPANDOROW:** stores linking information between a user and its values
  (contains tableId and userId refrences)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can add custom fields to user-entity and add them the field-values to user:

```
user.getExpandoBridge().addAttribute(...);
```

Custim field for the user-entity you can create by Control Panel `Portal->Custom Fields` or programmaticaly at liferay start.

The data will be stored in `ExpandoValue` tables.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case somebody try to retrieve the values from the custom fields and is having problems with null values returned by the method `user.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey")` (even when you followed the threads about permissions), I found other way to retrieve the Custom Fields values:

```java
ExpandoTable table = ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil.getDefaultTable(user.getCompanyId(), User.class.getName() );
ExpandoColumn column = ExpandoColumnLocalServiceUtil.getColumn(table.getTableId(), "yourCustomFieldKey");
ExpandoValue expandoValue = ExpandoValueLocalServiceUtil.getValue(table.getTableId(), column.getColumnId(), user.getUserId());
```

Then you can do a simple (if the field is text) `expandoValue.getString();`

Not so pretty, but do the work.

Answer (score 0):

User creation page in liferay can be customized. You can infact decide which fields to be present in the user creation page. **[More about this in here.](http://www.liferay.com/web/manish.gupta/blog/-/blogs/4951204)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands if you get the permission problem in adding or setting attribute.

```
user.getExpandoBridge().addAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey",false);
user.getExpandoBridge().setAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey", "valueForCustomField",false);
```