# Creating/Using User specific properties through Liferay API

Tags: properties, liferay

I am looking for class which can enable me to manage user specific properties.

In my portal different users have different properties so how can I make it using Liferay API.

For example I can show you how it works in JBoss Portal:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = this.userProfileModule.getProperties(portalUser);
```

and from other side we can add some new properties like this:

```
this.userProfileModule.setProperty(user, name, value);
```

I need such a mechanism.  I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You mean to say you need to have different fields for different users like for example Usera can have department,hobbies; Userb can have department,projects; Userc can have department,projects,hobbies etc

Answer (score 2):

You can find the "Custom Fields" in ControlPanel. The API for that is Expando* (search google for `liferay expando` and you'll find various docs, blog, wiki regarding its use)

Comment: This question might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136753/is-it-possible-to-add-extra-fields-under-create-user-in-liferay

Comment: can i make a hook which will switch com.liferay.portal.model.User class on my own class which already have this extra fields ? and this class extend User-impl so i have everything what i need in one simple class.