# Adding custom field to User programmatically through liferay.expando

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, expando

I am trying to add fields to `com.liferay.portal.model.User`, an extra attribute using `Expando`. Can someone explain to me how this method is adding a field because docs don't have much description.

```
private void addUserCustomAttribute(long companyId, ExpandoTable userExpandoTable, String attributeName, int type) throws PortalException, SystemException {

    ExpandoColumnLocalServiceUtil.getColumn(userExpandoTable.getTableId(), attributeName); //should be addColumn(long tableId, String name, int type) ???

} //and where can find type description couse i have very specific type, Map(String,Object) couse in ExpandoColumnConstants didn't see it
```

I have taken this from Liferay [Expando](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Expando) Wiki's [Adding User Custom Attributes](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding+User+Custom+Attributes+%28Liferay+v6%29).

When should I call this all? Where to put this in my project? What change is required or everything needs to be changed to call it.

Some good tutorial will be nice because it's hard to find something from 0 to end, always found only some part with no explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear. But if you simply want to add a custom attribute for your `User` then you can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171218/468763) and reproduced for your reference:

Custom field for the user-entity can be created through:
<kbd>Control Panel</kbd> `->` <kbd>Portal</kbd> `->` <kbd>Custom Fields</kbd> `->` <kbd>User</kbd>.

And programmatically can be created as follows:

```
user.getExpandoBridge().addAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey");
```

Then set the value as:

```
user.getExpandoBridge().setAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey", "valueForCustomField");
```

If your custom field is already present you can check like this:

```
if (user.getExpandoBridge().hasAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey")) { ... };
```

The data is stored in tables prefixed with **"EXPANDO"**:

- **EXPANDOCOLUMN:** stores the custom field key and other settings
  (contains the tableId refrences)
- **EXPANDODATA:** stores the custom field value for the key (contains the
  columnId and tableId refrences)
- **EXPANDOTABLE:** stores for which liferay entity (user) are you adding
  the custom field
- **EXPANDOROW:** stores linking information between a user and its values
  (contains tableId and userId refrences)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some useful information are contained but where and when use them, anytime(before using them of course),anywhere. How make Map<string,object> field ?

Comment: @user1506541 Wait a second, do you want to store an Expando of type Map<String, Object>?

Answer (score 0):

If your custom field is multivalue, you can use this:

```
String customVal = "yourCustomFieldValue";

user.getExpandoBridge().setAttribute("yourCustomFieldKey", new String[] {customVal }, false);
```

The last parameter set to "false" avoids permission check.